# Character string buffer too small error in Oracle

Tags: oracle

My table has the below data

```
Username Groupname
-------- ---------------
A        MAXADMIN
A        BUYER
B        PURCHASEMANAGER
B        FINANCECLERK
```

Output should be like below

```
Username Groupname 
-------- ----------------------------
A        MAXADMIN,BUYER
B        PURCHASEMANAGER,FINANCECLERK
```

I get an error `ORA-19011: character string buffer too small.`
Thanks in advance

```
  select maxuser.userid,
         person.displayname,
         maxuser.status,
         sod_Report.severity,
         sod_Report.scenario,
         RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, groupuser.groupname || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()'),',') groupname
    from maxuser,
         person,
         groupuser,
         sod_report
   where    maxuser.userid=person.personid
        and groupuser.userid = maxuser.userid
        and sod_report.userid= maxuser.userid
group by maxuser.userid,
         person.displayname,
         maxuser.status,
         sod_Report.severity,
         sod_Report.scenario
```

Comment: Who knows?  Did you run an explain plan?

Comment: Have a look at [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030). Maybe it is not necessary to generate a XML out from a string and then extract string again from this XML.

Comment: LISTAGG did worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-descriptive.

> #### 19011, 00000, "Character string buffer too small"
>
> **Cause:**  The string result asked for is too big to return back
>
> **Action:**  Get the result as a lob instead

You need to use the `DBMS_LOB` package to retrieve an `XMLTYPE` data table.
Here is an example which explains how to get the result as LOB.
[ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652879/ora-19011-character-string-buffer-too-small)

Answer (score 1):

we can use following function if we need to use more than 4000 characters -

```
select maxuser.userid,
         person.displayname,
         maxuser.status,
         sod_Report.severity,
         sod_Report.scenario,

         RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, groupuser.groupname || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()').getClobVal(),',') groupname

.....
```